# python tkinter window don't close with root.quit() when using os.system

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem. When in tkinter i use command `root.quit()` and then
`os.system("cmd")` the tkinter window does't close. Is there another way how to launch application?

here is a code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()
def a():
    root.quit()
    os.system("cmd")
open_select_file = tk.Button(canvas,
                        text = "close", 
                        command =  a,
                        font=(18)
                        ).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put your `os.system()` command at the very bottom, after `root.mainloop()`.  Note that your Python script will remain running until the launched command exits, it just won't have any windows open.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: simply use  `root.destroy()` instead of `root.quit()`

Comment: Yes this is possible but After that, i want open another tkinter window

Comment: yes possible you're trying to close 1st then open 2nd window @Klovik7

Comment: yes i want i am making simple Engine

Comment: So is there another way how to open some app?

Comment: if you're trying to open cmd then use 
    `root.destroy()`
    `os.system('cmd /c "date"')`
also, check here https://datatofish.com/command-prompt-python/  @Klovik7

Comment: Oh this works thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the solution if you're trying to open a command using python

your code changed `root.quit()` to  `root.destroy()`
and how to execute command
`os.system('cmd /k "Your Command Prompt Command"')`

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()
def a():
    root.destroy()
    os.system('cmd /c "date"')
open_select_file = tk.Button(canvas,
                        text = "close",
                        command =  a,
                        font=(18)
                        ).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

hope helpful for you

OUTPUT of CMD

[image: output of cmd]